# how to identify reason or troubleshoot memory overflow problem on esp32 - arduino

Tags: memory, arduino, overflow, esp32, reboot

I'm writing new arduino core(custom bord) for our new embedded development device. it using esp32 chip. now I'm writing some interrupt handling functions. it using function pointers on C and C++ mix environment.

I had some memory/stack overflow errors several. I have fixed it the very difficult way, because I haven't any idea of how to troubleshoot it. now again it has an error and it comes on using delay() function. but actually the problem is not in delay function, because I never change delay() function or it dependancy.

So I wont to know how to troubleshoot correct way these type memory overflow problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install this addon on your Arduino IDE:

https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder

This will parse your exception and give you a stack from your code.